# Android Studio not connecting to device

Tags: android-studio, flutter

So I am using android studio and developing a dart/flutter project. However, my device doesn't show up.when it's connected. I have tried everything but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: did you enable the developer option in your android device?

Comment: what is the output of flutter doctor while mobile is connected ?

Comment: @ diegoveloper Yea I did.

Comment: @ Viren V Varasadiya  where is that?

Comment: run command flutter doctor in terminal.